# Tax rate question

Tags: finance

How do you solve this question?

A company has taxable income $758,000. The federal tax is 35% of that portion
left after the state tax has been paid. The state tax is 15% of that portion after
federal tax has been paid. Find the federal and state taxes?

Comment: Write the conditions of the task as two equations. $x$ is federal tax, $y$ is state tax and $z$ is the taxable income.

Comment: Will both the federation and the state demand that their tax is deducted first? Either way, the company is left with $$0.65\times 0.85\times 758000 = 0.85\times 0.65\times 758000$$ But it is not clear how the federation and the state should "split" the tax between them if both think their tax is calculated first?

Answer (score 3):

Simply consider that the man has to pay x amount as FT and y amount as ST.

By the Situtation

x={35/100}{758000-y}

y={15/100}{758000-x}

[image]